# sql pick specific information of entire row according to another column

Tags: sql, date, conditional-statements

I have information of the following table:

```
Location_id |  Date_1    | Ex_Start    | EX_End    | Condition | Price
------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------+-------
   L_1      | 23-JUL-16  | 08-JUN-16   | 25-JUL-16 | EX        |  109
   L_1      | 23-JUL-16  | 28-JUL-16   | 31-JUL-16 | Non_EX    |  109
   L_1      | 24-JUL-16  | 08-JUN-16   | 25-JUL-16 | EX        |  89
   L_1      | 24-JUL-16  | 28-JUL-16   | 31-JUL-16 | Non_EX    |  89
   ...            ...          ...           ...       ...     
   L_2      | 23-JUL-16  | 24-JUL-16   | 15-AUG-16 | Non_EX    |  99
   L_2      | 23-JUL-16  | 26-OCT-16   | 29-JAN-17 | Non_EX    |  99
   L_2      | 24-JUL-16  | 24-JUL-16   | 15-AUG-16 | EX        |  79
   L_2      | 24-JUL-16  | 26-OCT-16   | 29-JAN-17 | Non_EX    |  79
   ...            ...          ...           ...       ...
```

"Date_1" is from current date to the same date next year. 
For the "Condition" column, "EX" means "Date_1" falls in EX period (between "EX_Start" and "Ex_End".
And for the "Condition" column, "Non_EX" means it does not fall in EX period, and "EX" means it falls in. 
I want to pick specific Date_1 information across all Location_id, and if there is one "Ex" for each location under the same date, condition would return "EX". Or it will Return "Non_EX'.

For example. this table will return:

```
Location_id |  Date_1    | Condition   | Price
------------+------------+-------------+-----------------------
   L_1      | 23-JUL-16  | EX          |  109
   L_1      | 24-JUL-16  | EX          |  89
   ...         ...          ...          ...
   L_2      | 23-JUL-16  | Non_EX      |  99
   L_2      | 24-JUL-16  | EX          |  79
   ...         ...          ...          ...
```

Thanks!

Comment: Which database (version) is this for? What did you try so far?

Comment: It is on Oracle SQL Developer 4.1.3, and haven't tried yet since I don't know how to put price into the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this would work for your case, please try.

```
 SELECT location,date1, min(condition),Price 
from location group by location, date1,Price
```

Updated to include price too.

Comment: Thanks, that works! But how can I put "price" information into the table?

Answer (score 0):

If for each combination of **location** and **date_1** the **price** is identical, follow @Prashant Majhwar. If, however, the **price** might differ between respective **EX** and **Non_EX**, you might want to try along

```
WITH
Data_Raw (location_ID, date_1, ex_Start, ex_End, condition, price) AS (
  SELECT 'L_1', '23-JUL-16', '08-JUN-16', '25-JUL-16', 'EX', 109 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L_1', '23-JUL-16', '28-JUL-16', '31-JUL-16', 'Non_EX', 110 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L_1', '24-JUL-16', '08-JUN-16', '25-JUL-16', 'EX', 89 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L_1', '24-JUL-16', '28-JUL-16', '31-JUL-16', 'Non_EX', 90 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L_2', '23-JUL-16', '24-JUL-16', '15-AUG-16', 'Non_EX', 99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L_2', '23-JUL-16', '26-OCT-16', '29-JAN-17', 'Non_EX', 99 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L_2', '24-JUL-16', '24-JUL-16', '15-AUG-16', 'EX', 79 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L_2', '24-JUL-16', '26-OCT-16', '29-JAN-17', 'Non_EX', 80 FROM DUAL
),
Data (location_ID, date_1, ex_Start, ex_End, condition, price) AS (
SELECT
  location_Id, TO_DATE(date_1, 'DD-MON-RR'), TO_DATE(ex_Start, 'DD-MON-RR')
  , TO_DATE(ex_End, 'DD-MON-RR'), condition, price
FROM Data_Raw
)
SELECT DISTINCT
  M.location_ID
  , TO_CHAR (M.date_1, 'DD-MON-RR') date_1
  , M.condition
  , D.price
FROM  
  (SELECT
    location_ID
    , date_1
    , MIN(condition) condition
  FROM Data
  GROUP BY location_ID, date_1
  ) M
JOIN Data D
  ON M.location_ID = D.location_ID
  AND M.date_1 = D.date_1
  AND M.condition = D.condition
ORDER BY location_id, date_1
;
```

It:

- uses a subselect to zoom in on the wanted **condition**,
- `JOIN`s back to your data to pull in the price (and would allow to do so with the other columns as well - as suggested by your question's title), and
- `DISTINCT`s to prevent duplicate rows for **Non_EX**

Please comment if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.